# PF5 <p:tree><p:ajax listener> stops working after being refreshed via <p:contextMenu><p:menuItem>, works in PF4

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tree, listener

I am using PF5, Jboss7, Mojarra 2.2 with Jdk1.7.
I have a dynamic tree with context menu. When I click on the menuitem, the page appears in the content panel. However, after that, looks like i lose all the listeners on the page including the tree.  Cannot expand, second menuitem does not respond, basically, primefaces removes all the listeners on the page or, perhaps removes the form component, not sure.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
   xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
   xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
   xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
   <title>IPMS Navigation Tree</title>
   <h:outputStylesheet library="stylesheet" name="lookfeel.css" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
   <p:layout fullPage="true">
      <p:layoutUnit position="west" resizable="true" size="400"
         minSize="100">
         <h:form id="navForm" prependId="false">
            <p:tabView>
                 <p:tab title="Domains">
                     <ui:include src="TabDomains.xhtml"/>
                 </p:tab>
                 <p:tab title="Orgs">
                     <ui:include src="TabOrgs.xhtml"/>
                 </p:tab>
                 <p:tab title="Admin">
                     <ui:include src="TabAdmin.xhtml"/>
                 </p:tab>
             </p:tabView>
         </h:form>
      </p:layoutUnit>

      <p:layoutUnit position="center">
         <h:form id="frmContent" prependId="false">
            <p:panel id="frmPanel">
               <ui:include src="#{menuController.page}.xhtml" />
            </p:panel>
         </h:form>
      </p:layoutUnit>
   </p:layout>
</h:body>
</html>
```

TabDomains.xhtml is

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <p:tree id="domains" value="#{treeController.root}" 
        selectionMode="single"
         selection="#{treeController.selectedDomain}"
        var="node" dynamic="true" cache="false">
        <p:ajax event="expand" listener="#{treeController.onNodeExpand}" />
        <p:treeNode>
            <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
        </p:treeNode>
    </p:tree>
    <p:contextMenu for="domains">
        <p:menuitem id="propertiesMenu" value="Properties" update=":frmContent:frmPanel"
            actionListener="#{menuController.viewDomainProperties}">
            </p:menuitem>
        <p:menuitem id="editZoneMenu" value="Edit Zone" update=":frmContent:frmPanel"
            actionListener="#{menuController.viewEditZone}" 
            icon="ui-icon-close">
            </p:menuitem>
    </p:contextMenu>
</ui:composition>
```

And the backing bean is:

```
public class MenuController extends Controller
{
   private static final Logger logger = Logger.getInstance(MenuController.class);

   private String page;

   public MenuController()
   {
      super();
      this.page="MainContent";
   }

   public String getPage()
   {
      return page;
   }

   public void setPage(String page)
   {
      this.page = page;
   }

   public void viewEditZone()
   {
      logger.debug("begin viewEditZone");
      this.page="EditZone";
   }

   public void viewDomainProperties()
   {
      logger.debug("begin viewDomainProperties");
      this.page="DomainProperties";
   }
}
```

I tested this in PF4 and it works fine. Any help or pointer to fix this is greatly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Tested this in latest 5.0.8 as well with the same result.

Comment: Alright, It is working now. I am not sure what fixed it but I basically removed started from fresh with 5.0.8. Perhaps i had some stuff that was left from PF4 that was hindering the processing. Its working fine now.